# How will I be able to get the value of this auto generated id I want them to be displayed in my recyclerview

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase database:

[image]

I want to display the value of the auto-generated id given by the push method

this is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);


    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    String key = newRef.getKey();
    preRef.child(key).get();

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    preRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Calendar calendar = dataSnapshot.getValue(Calendar.class);
                list.add(calendar);
            }
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

I cant display the value of the Uid can someone please help me?

Comment: Totally unrelated but you're ever going to sort your dates, storing them in that format will be an issue. Try a yyyymmdd format as it ensures they are always sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To display the list of dates, you can do:

```
DatabaseReference actlogRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ActLog");
actlogRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.child("date").getChildren()) {
            String date = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(date);
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

For this, `list` will have to be a list of strings, as that's what you store in the database. If you must use a list of `Date` objects, have a look at questions about [parsing a data from a string in java](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+parse+string+to+date+in+java).